# Efficiently querying/ordering by Sum aggregate in related model in EfCore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm still fairly new to C#, .NET and EfCore so please bear with me and apologies if I'm missing something in the question.

Let's say I have the following relations

```
public class User
{
    public Account Account {get; set;}
    public string Foo {get; set;}

}

public class Account
{
    public List<Transaction> Transactions {get; set;}
}

public class Transaction
{
    public decimal Amount {get; set;}
    public TransactionType TransactionType {get; set;}

}

public enum TransactionType 
{
    Credit = 1,
    Debit = 2,
    Refund = 3,
}
```

I'd like to work with balances, which need to be calculated every time the User model is retrieved. For this example, let's say I need to order a list of users, where Foo is "Bar", by their account balance

```
var query = db.Users
    .Include(u => u.Account)
    .ThenInclude(a => a.Transactions)
    .Where(u => u.Foo == "Bar");

var orderedQuery = query
         .OrderByDescending(u => 
              (u.Account.Transactions
                .Where(t => t.TransactionType == TransactionType.Credit || t.TransactionType == TransactionType.Refund)
                .Sum(t => t.Amount)) 
              - u.Account.Transactions
                 .Where(t => t.TransactionType == TransactionType.Debit)
                 .Sum(t => t.Amount)
              )
);


// Build the List
return orderedQuery.Skip(...).Take(...).Select(x => new SomeDTO{/* Build some DTO's with User Info, Account Info and Balance */}).ToList();
```

The above works, but is inefficient.

I'm working on a fairly large codebase and existing database in a asp.net core & sql-server project, so I need to work with what I've got. Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this kind of work?

Comment: You could store sums of such separately in another table instead of calculating them every time on the flight

Comment: `Include` is *only* needed to eagerly load related entities that aren't used in the query. They aren't needed here. You don't need ordering either. You wouldn't use `ORDER BY` in a SQL query that simply returned a total after all.

Comment: What are you trying to actually do? Order accounts by their total transaction profit? Instead of multiple GROUPings you could calculate the amount's sign based on the transaction type and simply sum all amounts in a *single* GROUP over `Accounts`

Comment: I'm building a DTO list that I'm sending back to a controller. It's a table of Users and one of the columns is "Account Balance". The business user wishes to see the list of customer users ordered by balance. There are tens of thousands of customer users.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need all these `Include`s? They are not necessary for the ordering aggregation later.

```cs
var query = db.Users
    .Include(u => u.Account)
    .ThenInclude(a => a.Transactions)
    .Where(u => u.Foo == "Bar");
```

---

You can optimize the ordering part of the query, by combining into a single grouping

```cs
var orderedQuery = query.OrderByDescending(u =>
    u.Account.Transactions
    .GroupBy(t => 1)
    .Select(g =>
          g.Where(t => t.TransactionType == TransactionType.Credit || t.TransactionType == TransactionType.Refund)
           .Sum(t => t.Amount)
        - g.Where(t => t.TransactionType == TransactionType.Debit)
           .Sum(t => t.Amount)
        )
    );
```

`Skip` `Take` is pretty inefficient, as it requires searching through the whole list again. It may be prudent to cache it all in the client and page it afterwards.

Comment: The Includes are to get data required to build the list of DTO's which I'm sending back to the view (a table, in this case).

What does the GroupBy(t => 1) do?

Comment: Groups by the empty set. It's the equivalent in SQL of `GROUP BY ()` or aggregating with no `GROUP BY` at all